# mhchem wants expl3

Tags: texlive, ubuntu, expl3, mhchem

I am on Ubuntu using TexLive and I cannot compile this .tex file:

```
\documentclass[
letter,
12pt         %% set default font size to 12 point
]{scrartcl}  %% article, see KOMA documentation (scrguide.dvi)

%just have this
%\usepackage{ucs} breaks biblatex?
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage[american]{babel}

\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}

\usepackage[
    backend=biber,
    style=authoryear-icomp,
    sortlocale=de_DE,
    natbib=true,
    url=false, 
    doi=true,
    eprint=false
]{biblatex}

\addbibresource{references-biblatex.bib}

\usepackage[hidelinks]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=false,
}


\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amstext}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{siunitx}

%\usepackage{expl3} % i thought i might have to include it

\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}      %chemical notation

\title{Not very minimal Example}
\author{Test Name}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle


\tableofcontents

Test

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

I when remove the mhchem package it works, but I need it for my lab report.

With the mhchem package I get following message:

```
/texmf/tex/latex/l3kernel/l3str.sty
*****************************************************************
** 
** Package l3str is obsolete and has been removed!
** 
** Its functionality is now only provided as part of in the expl3 package
** 
** After showing you an error message you can hit <return> we will continue
** for now by loading expl3 for you. However, at some point in the future
** the old packages will be removed.
** 
** Therefore, please replace '\usepackage{l3str}'
** with '\usepackage{expl3}' in your documents as soon as possible.
** 
*******************************************************************

! Package l3str Error: This package is obsolete --- use 'expl3' instead.

See the l3str package documentation for explanation.
Type  H <return>  for immediate help.
 ...                                              

l.72    use 'expl3' instead}
```

It don't really know how to fix that. I tried following things:

- remove/install l3kernel
- compile it on a Windows machine with TeXStudio (works there!)
- googling arround, not understanding what could be the problem

The fact that it works on Windows should tell me that my latex installation is somehow not setup correctly and I might have to install some other packege? (via tlmgr)

I hope somebody can help me, I like latex a lot but it's very intimidating at first. :)

Comment: On an up-to-date TeX Live system you should be fine. What _exactly_ do you have installed?

Comment: I've noticed that ubuntu quite often lags behind the latest TeX Live. Did you install your TeX distribution through ubuntu's software manager or did you directly install TeX Live (e.g from DVD or download from TUG)?

Comment: So - I honestly don't remember - it was a couple of months back and I do not want to tell you some speculation how I did it back then.. Is there a way to find out what exactly is installed?

Comment: I use fedora rather than ubuntu, but I expect if it was installed using the software manager it should show up as installed if you open the software manager. In which case, you should be able to uninstall it through the software manager and then [download and install the latest TeX Live](http://tug.org/texlive/), but you might want to wait for advice from a ubuntu user first. I always install TeX Live from the DVD and then use `tlmgr` to update (`sudo tlmgr update --all`).

Comment: It shows more than 20 packages in the Software Center of Ubuntu for TeX Live - should I just deinstall every single one of them?
`sudo tlmgr update --all` says there are no updates available

Comment: Don't just uninstall them. You need to also supply a dummy package to take care of dependencies. See [this question and answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu?s=7|1.2376) for details of how to do this on Debian/Ubuntu. (Not hard to adapt to other GNU/Linux distros, but the focus is on Debian-based systems.)

Comment: Wait, is this the only way to get a properly running TeX Live installation? With all the dummy packages and so on?
Because I can run the TeXLive Manager 2015 right now and it seems to be working (except for mhchem) and me making fake packages for Ubuntu seems like I could break it even more.
Edit: Especially because I don't know what will be wrong when it works for some time and then it breaks, after an update or something like that.

Comment: Not the only way to get a properly running one, but the only way to get a current one if your distro doesn't provide current packages.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the error was caused by outdated packages.