# Server error compiling big documents, ShareLatex

Tags: sharelatex, compilation-error

I am trying to compile a large document with several chapters in ShareLatex. Each Chapter compiles correctly with minor (often unavoidable) errors but when I try to compile more than 2 chapters together I get the following error: Server error, Sorry, something went wrong and your project could not be compiled. Please try again in a few moments. Trying again later does nothing to rectify the issue. This is in draft mode as well so images are not the issue.

EDIT: MWE included

```
\documentclass[12pt, twoside]{report} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} 
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage{array}
\doublespacing
\usepackage[a4paper, left=40mm, top=25mm, right=20mm, bottom=25mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx} 
\graphicspath{{Images/}{../Images/}} 
\usepackage[outdir=./]{epstopdf}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.5}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[justification=justified]{caption}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{fancyhdr} 
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhead{}                                
\fancyhead[C]{Chapter \thechapter} 
\setlength{\headheight}{14.5pt}
\fancyfoot{}                                
\fancyfoot[RO,LE]{\thepage}  
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem} %for equations
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{xparse}
\NewDocumentCommand{\cecount}{ O{#2} m }{\ce{#2} (\cmpd{#1})}
\usepackage{etoolbox,calc}
\makeatletter
\pretocmd{\@makechapterhead}{\setcounter{cmpdmain}{100*\thechapter-1}}{}{}
\makeatother
\usepackage[journal = angew]{chemstyle}
\cstsetup{radhyphen = false,radsuper = true,abbremph = true}
\usepackage{chemscheme}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[backend = biber, style=chem-angew]{biblatex} 
\addbibresource{mendeley.bib}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Introduction}
   \input{Chapters/chapter1.tex} 
   \input{Chapters/chapter2.tex}
etc...
```

Comment: Everything will remain pure speculation unless you don't provide a Minimal Working Example.

Comment: What happens when you compile locally?

Comment: I am trying to compile locally now to see if that works, thanks for the suggestion. MWE added above

Comment: It will compile locally but my references (biblatex) are now not working and the headers and footers and page numbers are messed up!

Comment: the example you posted isn't a "MWE" as no one can run it as it relies on  `\input{Chapters/chapter1.tex} ` and  `etc...`  to be useful the posted code needs to be something peopel can run to trace and debug the problem

Comment: The comment `compiles correctly with minor (often unavoidable) errors` is very suspicious, no tex errors are unavoidable, and given tex's error recovery strategies I would never use any pdf generated by a tex run that makes any error. But you have not said what errors you get or given any other indication  of the problem.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle My apologies, I misunderstood the meaning of MWE however I feel that it is not so helpful in this case. The thesis compiles locally and each individual chapter compiles the problem is compiling the entire document together on ShareLatex. There is no MWE short of giving you my entire thesis which i cannot . WRT to minor errors I refereed  to they are underfull and overfull text boxes and  what as far as I can tell is a bug in the mhchem package see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/289196/mhchem-wants-expl3.

Comment: I say the under/overfull text boxes are unavoidable as they are due to having lots of chemical equations that latex doesn't format so well and I have used sloppypar to correct them. Could this be the problem?

Comment: underfull or overfull boxes to not give errors (and can not be relate to the sharelatex issue)  are you sure it wasn't as it says, a server issue that may be gone if you try again later? Otherwise if you can not make a reproducible test case, there is probably nothing we can do here and you should contact support at sharelatex as they _can_ see the logs of what crashes your project.